# How to aggregate by day with multiple columns [Pyspark]?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert below pandas code to pysaprk.

```
d = {'has_discount':'count',
    'clearance':'count',
    'count': ['count', 'sum'],
    'price_guide':'max'}

df.index = timestamp2datetime(df.time_create, unit='ms')
df1 = df.resample('D').agg(d)

df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
d1 = {'has_discount_count':'discount_order_count',
    'clearance_count':'clearance_order_count',
    'count_count':'order_count',
    'count_sum':'sale_count',
    'price_guide_max':'price_guide'}

df2 = df1.rename(columns=d1)
```

However there is no resmaple in pysaprk, try to use groupby instead:

```
d = {'has_discount':'count',
    'clearance':'count',
    'count': ['count', 'sum'],
    'price_guide':'max'}

df.select(date_format(from_unixtime(df.time_create/1000),'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('day')).groupby('day').agg(d).show(5)
```

But got error

```
AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name "price_guide" among (day);'
```

Pyspark's aggregation seems not support input like `d` . What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.select` you're using leave you with only one column `day`, but in aggregation statetement you're using  other columns.
What you probably want, is to add column `day` to others that exists:

`df.withColumn('day', date_format(from...`

Comment: Thank you, that is a problem. The left one is pyspark `agg` function doesn't accept  `d = { 'count': ['count', 'sum'] }` ,  do I have to split `count` and `sum` into two aggregation?

Comment: I usually use following syntax: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` `....agg(F.count(df.col1), F.sum(df.col1), F.max(df.col3)`